# Alamofire request in swift 5

Tags: alamofire, ios13, swift5, xcode11.3

I have used `Alamofire` in one of my application. Now Application needs to update. So I have updated `Alamofire` pods with new version.

Now I don't know how to call `Alamofire` request in swift 5 with new version of `Alamofire`. I have tried, but it's throwing error. I have searched lot, but not found ny solution.

Can anyone help me to make a call with `Alamofire`?

Errors :

> 1. Protocol type 'Any' cannot conform to 'Encodable' because only concrete types can conform to protocols
> 2. Value of type 'Result' has no member 'isFailure'
> 3. Value of type 'Result' has no member 'error'

[image: A]

Answer (score 3):

I have created a sample app just to give an idea

```
struct Article: Codable {
    let firstName: String
    let lastName: String
    let email: String
}

struct User: Encodable {
    let name: String
    let password: String
}
// data model
let userStruct = User(name: "test", password: "pass")

// data dictionary
let userDictionary = ["name": "test", "password": "pass"]

func getData() {
        let headers: HTTPHeaders = ["Access-Token-Key": ""]
        let request = AF.request(url,
                   method: .post,
                   parameters: userDictionary,   // or 'userStruct' because both conform to 'Encodable' parameters.
                   encoder: JSONParameterEncoder.default,
                   headers: headers)
        // Receive and decode the server's JSON response.
        request.responseDecodable(of: Article.self) { response in
           switch response.result {
           case let .success(result):
              // the decoded result of type 'Article' that you received from the server.
            print("Result is: \(result)")
           case let .failure(error):
              // Handle the error.
            print("Error description is: \(error.localizedDescription)")
           }
        }
    }
```

If you want to use `parameters` of type `[String: Any]` then use `Alamofire version 4.9.1`. The version which I used in the sample app is `5.0.0-rc.3`